# Javascript 'range' equivilent

Tags: javascript, loops

So I have a div with a number if images in it and I want to count those images and display and the count thus:

If there are 5 images:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

If this were python or PHP, I would simply get the number of images and then iterate through a 'foreach' loop. However I can't figure how to do this with Javascript.

I am counting the number of images this way:

```
<script>
$(document.body).ready(function() {
var n = $("#gallery img").length;
});
</script>
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this using javascript?

Comment: What is it you want to do? You have the number of elements -- why do you want to iterate through them? You probably want the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

Comment: Well, I have a slideshow gallery that I would like to add links where the user can click and jump to say 'image 3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document.body).ready(function() {
var n = $("#gallery img").length;
var $elementToAppend = $("#elementToAppend");
if (n > 0)
    $elementToAppend.append("0");
for(var i=1; i<n; i++)
    $elementToAppend.append("," + i);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am after, however, I can't seem to get it to work. I have created a <div id="elementToAppend"></div> but nothing appears. Any ideas?

Comment: debug the code using Firebug or something. Check if the value of "n" is greater than 0 and if $elementToAppend really has length of 1. If everything checks, this code must work